# IText 7 convert html to PDF

Tags: java, itext7

I am using itext 7 to convert html to pdf, however, for some font styles, words with some special characters are being ignored, how can I solve this?

I am using DefaultFontProvider but it does not resolve. The code I am using.

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, true);
properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
List<IElement> list = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new FileInputStream(src), properties);
for (IElement element : list) {
    if (element instanceof IBlockElement) {
        document.add((IBlockElement) element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Font styles, such as **bold** or _italic_, or font typeface such as `Courier` or Arial?  What characters?

Comment: Styles like Arial, Ani, etc ...

Comment: When I use for example the Ani font and I export to pdf, itext ignores all letters that have special character. Ex: Téste leaves Tste.

Comment: Does your HTML declare its text encoding?

Comment: yes, <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

Comment: Hi, your problem description is very vague. Please attach an HTML to reproduce the problem. If some characters are sometimes being ignored, how can someone reproduce the problem?